# Use the session object UserBean across dao methods

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I get an Object say UserBean something like this from the session

```
public class UserBean {

    private String username;
    private String userid;
    private String userType;
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }
    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

}
```

Now i want to use this bean in many of my dao methods. The problem i face is i have to modify my dao parameters to include this bean info  which i think will not be a good design.

How can i include UserBean Details without modifying my DAO methods ?

I am using spring MVC 3

Comment: Are you using Hibernate? If so, you could potentially use an interceptor to add this data transparently.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a good idea to access web context classes in your DAO, this will introduce a tight coupling among the layers and changing something in the presentation layer might effect your DAO layer objects. You can pass this information to your DAO classes as a method parameter instead.

But if you really want to get access to session attributes in your DAO, you can use `RequestContextHolder` for this:

```
ServletRequestAttributes request = (ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
            .currentRequestAttributes();
HttpSession session = request.getRequest().getSession();
UserBean UserBean = (UserBean)session.getAttribute("userBean");
```

As you are referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, you need to add `RequestContextListener` to your web.xml to expose the current request:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: if the application is running on Spring MVC, you don't need to add the Listner in web.xml

Answer (score 0):

DAO layer should not be aware of the web session.
Implement session related logic in 'upper' layer, in manager or service.
In your 'refactoring' case it would have an added benefit of acting as an adapter between Spring MVC layer and DAO, beside being good design.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance variable in your DAO class and one setter and getter for that.

But before calling any DAO method you have to set userBean in that DAO which is again not good practice but may be one of the solution.

Comment: This won't work for concurrent requests assuming DAO is singleton bean.

Answer (score 0):

You could define UserBean as a Spring bean and use Spring's session scope. E.g.:

```xml
<bean id="user" class="com.foo.UserBean" scope="session">
  <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDao" class="com.foo.UserDao">
  <property name="user" ref="user"/>
</bean>
```

For documentation, see [3.5.4.5 Scoped beans as dependencies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) in the Spring documentation.